# Conditional logic and variables in pipe to determine value for dd skip

Tags: pipe, dd

I am using dd to return a stream of data from tape. I want to send this via a pipe that will extract the byte range I require. I need to check for the presence of a string in the initial bytes, and based on that value the byte range will differ. Something like this...

`dd if=/dev/tape/st0 bs=512K | { var=1; if [[ $(head -c13) == "././@LongLink" ]]; then var=3; } | dd of=extracted_file.bin skip=$(512*$var) iflag=skip_bytes`

However, I understand that a variable cannot be referenced after the pipe segment in which it is defined.

**EDIT**

Based on kusalananda's comment, I think the best way to achieve may actual goal is to restore a single block from the tape, get the info I need, then rewind and restore the whole file using dd and the calculated value for skip. This is because there doesn't seem to be any reliable way to remove bytes from the beginning of a file inplace (unlike for the end, where we have truncate)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the following untested code:

```
dd if=/dev/tape/st0 bs=512K |
{
    skip=512
    if [[ $( head -c 13 ) == "././@LongLink" ]]; then
        skip=$(( skip*3 ))
    fi
    dd of=extracted_file.bin skip="$skip" iflag=skip_bytes
}
```

This passes the data from the initial `dd` into a compound command.  The compound command sets `skip` (I renamed your variable) to some number and calls `dd`.  The second `dd` will read from standard input, which is inherited from the compound command, which gets it from the initial `dd`.

Note that the second `dd` will not see the data read by the `head` call! Also, *some* `head` implementations may read more data than requested, which may cause the second `dd` to see too little data. GNU `head` (which is what you're using here) seems to be well behaved in this respect.

Comment: `dd` has `skip` and `count`, but you need to know ahead of time to generate the proper command line.

Comment: @AaronD.Marasco I only address the actual issue in the question, i.e. how a variable may be used as part of a stage in a pipeline. If the `dd` commands works or not, I have no way of testing. Mostly because I don't use a Unix where the `dd` command takes the parameters used in the code.

Comment: @kusalananda could we read a block of 512 bytes assign the variable, and then write the same block to stdout, so that the 2nd dd command sees all the data?

Comment: @swami Update your question with your requirements. I may delete this answer if I feel I can't address those requirements.

Comment: @Kusalananda Pls don't delete. It's a good answer. Just seeing if it can be refined a little. Requirements are the same. It doesn't seem 100% robust if we don't know for sure what remaining portion of the data is getting sent to the 2nd dd command

Comment: @swami Well, one solution would be to read the first bit of the tape, set the variable conditionally, rewind, and then do a simpler pipeline.